# Should the btrfs nodesize and lvmcache chunksize be tuned together

Tags: lvm, btrfs

When using btrfs with lvmcache, are there any considerations for tuning the lvmcache "chunksize" and btrfs "nodesize" parameters wrt each other?

Ie, perhaps there is an advantage to having both set the same?

(The default lvmcache chunksize is 32KiB, and the default btrfs nodesize is 16KiB.)